# Creating user programmatically fails with Postgres

Tags: users, 9

Anyone know what's wrong here? After the D8->D9 upgrade, a stupidly simple piece of code is not working, has there been a change? It worked before.

```
$params = [
  'name' => $username,
  'pass' => $password,
  'mail' => $email,
  'init' => $email,
];

$user = $this->users->create($params);

$user->enforceIsNew();
$user->save();
```

In D8 this was fine, in D9 I'm getting:

```
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column "uid" of relation "drupal_users" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, 740f7084-de66-4572-8ec7-049376cf5a33, en).: INSERT INTO "drupal_users" ("uuid", "langcode") VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1);
```

Research tells me that there was a change from D8 to D9.5 where the UID field is now a serial field instead of an integer using the sequence API.

In Postgres, you either omit the serial field, or use "DEFAULT".

The UID field is not being omitted but it's set to NULL. If I try to force it to be DEFAULT it gets type-cast to 0 (zero) and we get the UID already exists error.

How on earth can I create this user programmatically?

Comment: Can you compare the users table schema against that of a fresh install to be sure this isn’t just a missed update?

Comment: You are referring to https://www.drupal.org/node/838992. It would be good to include that research link in the question.

Comment: What object is `$this->users`?

Comment: There is no need to call `enforceIsNew()` as that is already done from the entity storage. I hope `$this->users` contains an entity storage instance for the User entity.

Comment: $this->users is the user entity storage - looks like it might be a missed update on the test site. But must be okay on production because that's not generating any issues, (Ha, I'd soon hear about it if it was.)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there was a database update that hadn't been run on the test site, the one that switched the users.UID column to being serial, instead of int.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of explicitly setting the "uid" value in your code, you can let the database handle it by omitting it from the $params array.

Comment: They are not specifying the uid.